# Is it possible to call a C# delegate by method name

Tags: c#

Instead of

```
if (somecondition == 1) 
{
    int result = new myDelegate(MyClass.myMethod1); 
}
else 
{
    int result = new myDelegate(MyClass.myMethod2);
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this

```
int result = new myDelegate("MyClass.myMethod" + i.ToString()); }
```

Comment: This code is incorrect, you can't assign a delegate to an int...

Comment: Not really important, but you should try to let your c#-code look like c#-code, so curly-brackets always go into next line, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myDelegate dlg = (myDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(myDelegate), this, "myMethod" + i);
```

Comment: @programmernovice: You did ask for a delegate. Reed Copsey's answer merely invokes a method dynamically whereas Thomas and others create a delegate for you as your request seemed to suggest you wanted.

Comment: The advantage of this method is that the delegate you obtain is an order (or two) of magnitude faster to invoke than invoking it through reflection every time. Only the first reflection call here is (relatively) slow, invoking it every time after though is nearly as fast as a normal method call and insignicant enough to not matter. Think of it as caching reflection.

Comment: Good, but even better to use `Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type, Object, String)` overload and avoid dealing with `MethodInfo` at all.

Comment: @Pavel: Good one, I forgot that overload... I edited my answer

Comment: @Jason you're right I asked for delegates so I attributed the good answer to you ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this via Reflection (but I don't necessarily recommend it):

```
string MethodName = "myMethod" + i.ToString();
Type type = MyClass.GetType();
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(MethodName);
int result = (int) methodInfo.Invoke(MyClass, null);
```

Comment: I voted for Thomas because he answered first but I would rather use your solution as it is easier for my mind.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me, but...  You are free mark either as an answer - but normally, vote for the one you decide is the one you want to use.  Answering first (although technically, I answered 1 minute before him, btw) doesn't mean answering best. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can dynamically invoke methods using reflection. Small sample:

```
public class MyClass {
    public delegate string MyDelegate();
    public string MyMethod1() {
        return "Hello";
    }
    public string MyMethod2() {
        return "Bye";
    }
}

int i;
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
MethodInfo method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod" + i.ToString());
Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyClass.MyDelegate), myInstance, method);
Console.WriteLine(del()); // prints "Hello" or "Bye" contingent on value of i
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, needed just too long for this, but after i've done this, I'm gonna post this too ;-)

BEWARE: Reflektion is far far slower than using delegates!

```
Type t = typeof(MainClass);
MethodInfo mi = null;
int i = 2;
if (i==1) 
{
    mi = t.GetMethod("myMethod" + i.ToString());
}
else 
{
    mi = t.GetMethod("myMethod" + i.ToString());
}   

if(mi != null)
{
    mi.Invoke(new object(), new object[] {});
}
```